# Swift Compile Perfomance is too slowly for a simple source code

Tags: swift, xcode, performance

I trying to make a little Swift 3 code to convert Sonar Date to Lunar Date.
A very tiny code, but Xcode take around 10 minutes to compile that.
Could you please give me some advice to improve performance.
Here are my swift code:

```
class DateExtensions {
    let PI: Double = M_PI

    func jdFromDate(day: Int, month: Int, year: Int) ->Int {
        let a: Int = (14 - month) / 12
        let y: Int = year + 4800 - a
        let m: Int = month + 12 * a - 3
        var jd: Int = day + (153 * m + 2)/5 + 365 * y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 - 32045

        if (jd < 2299161) {
            jd = day + (153 * m + 2)/5 + 365 * y + y/4 - 32083
        }

        return jd
    }

    func jdToDate(_ jd: Int) -> [Int] {
        var a: Int = 0
        var b: Int = 0
        var c: Int = 0

        if (jd > 2299160) { // After 5/10/1582, Gregorian calendar
            a = jd + 32044
            b = (4 * a + 3) / 146097
            c = a - (b * 146097) / 4
        } else {
            b = 0
            c = jd + 32082
        }
        let d: Int = (4 * c + 3)/1461
        let e: Int = c - (1461 * d)/4
        let m: Int = (5 * e + 2)/153
        let day: Int = e - (153 * m + 2)/5 + 1
        let month: Int = m + 3 - 12 * (m/10)
        let year: Int = b * 100 + d - 4800 + m/10

        return [day, month, year]
    }

    func SunLongitude(_ jdn: Double) -> Double {
        return SunLongitudeAA98(jdn)
    }

    func SunLongitudeAA98(_ jdn: Double) -> Double {
        let T: Double = (jdn - 2451545.0 ) / 36525 // Time in Julian centuries from 2000-01-01 12:00:00 GMT
        let T2: Double = T * T
        let dr: Double = PI/180 // degree to radian
        let M: Double = 357.52910 + 35999.05030 * T - 0.0001559 * T2 - 0.00000048 * T * T2 // mean anomaly, degree
        let L0: Double = 280.46645 + 36000.76983 * T + 0.0003032 * T2 // mean longitude, degree
        var DL: Double = (1.914600 - 0.004817 * T - 0.000014 * T2) * sin(dr * M)
        DL = DL + (0.019993 - 0.000101 * T) * sin(dr * 2 * M) + 0.000290 * sin(dr * 3 * M)
        var L: Double = L0 + DL // true longitude, degree
        L = Double(L - 360 * (INT(L/360))) // Normalize to (0, 360)

        return L
    }

    func NewMoon(_ k: Int) -> Double {
        return NewMoonAA98(k)
    }

    func NewMoonAA98(_ k: Int) -> Double {
        var T: Double = k/1236.85 // Time in Julian centuries from 1900 January 0.5
        var T2: Double = T * T
        var T3: Double = T2 * T
        var dr: Double = PI/180
        var Jd1: Double = Double(2415020.75933 + 29.53058868*k + 0.0001178*T2 - 0.000000155*T3)
        Jd1 = Jd1 + 0.00033*sin((166.56 + 132.87*T - 0.009173*T2)*dr) // Mean new moon
        var M: Double = Double(359.2242 + 29.10535608*k - 0.0000333*T2 - 0.00000347*T3) // Sun's mean anomaly
        var Mpr: Double = Double(306.0253 + 385.81691806*k + 0.0107306*T2 + 0.00001236*T3) // Moon's mean anomaly
        var F: Double = Double(21.2964 + 390.67050646*k - 0.0016528*T2 - 0.00000239*T3) // Moon's argument of latitude
        var C1: Double = (0.1734 - 0.000393*T)*sin(M*dr) + 0.0021*sin(2*dr*M)
        C1 = C1 - 0.4068*sin(Mpr*dr) + 0.0161*sin(dr*2*Mpr)
        C1 = C1 - 0.0004*sin(dr*3*Mpr)
        C1 = C1 + 0.0104*sin(dr*2*F) - 0.0051*sin(dr*(M+Mpr))
        C1 = C1 - 0.0074*sin(dr*(M-Mpr)) + 0.0004*sin(dr*(2*F+M))
        C1 = C1 - 0.0004*sin(dr*(2*F-M)) - 0.0006*sin(dr*(2*F+Mpr))
        C1 = C1 + 0.0010*sin(dr*(2*F-Mpr)) + 0.0005*sin(dr*(2*Mpr+M))
        var deltat: Double = 0

        if (T < -11) {
            deltat = 0.001 + 0.000839 * T + 0.0002261 * T2 - 0.00000845 * T3 - 0.000000081 * T * T3
        } else {
            deltat = -0.000278 + 0.000265 * T + 0.000262 * T2
        }

        let JdNew: Double = Jd1 + C1 - deltat

        return JdNew
    }

    func INT(_ d: Double) -> Int {
        return Int(exactly: floor(d))!
    }

    func getSunLongitude(_ dayNumber: Int, _ timeZone: Double) -> Double {
        return SunLongitude(dayNumber - 0.5 - timeZone/24)
    }

    func getNewMoonDay(_ k: Int, _ timeZone: Double) -> Int {
        let jd: Double = NewMoon(k)
        return INT(jd + 0.5 + timeZone/24)
    }

    func getLunarMonth11(_ yy: Int, _ timeZone: Double) -> Int {
        var off: Double = jdFromDate(31, 12, yy) - 2415021.076998695
        var k: Int = INT(off / 29.530588853)
        var nm: Int = getNewMoonDay(k, timeZone)
        var sunLong: Int = INT(getSunLongitude(nm, timeZone)/30)

        if (sunLong >= 9) {
            nm = getNewMoonDay(k-1, timeZone)
        }

        return nm
    }
    func getLeapMonthOffset(_ a11: Int, _ timeZone: Double) -> Int {
        var k: Int = INT(0.5 + (a11 - 2415021.076998695) / 29.530588853)
        var last: Int = 0 // Month 11 contains point of sun longutide 3*PI/2 (December solstice)
        var i: Int = 1 // We start with the month following lunar month 11
        var arc = INT(getSunLongitude(getNewMoonDay(k+i, timeZone), timeZone)/30)

        repeat {
            last = arc
            i = i + 1
            arc = INT(getSunLongitude(getNewMoonDay(k+i, timeZone), timeZone)/30)
        } while (arc != last && i < 14)

        return i - 1
    }

    func convertSolar2Lunar(_ dd: Int, _ mm: Int, _ yy: Int, _ timeZone: Double) -> [Int] {
        var lunarDay: Int = 0
        var lunarMonth: Int = 0
        var lunarYear: Int = 0
        var lunarLeap: Int = 0
        var dayNumber: Int = jdFromDate(dd, mm, yy)
        var k: Int = INT((dayNumber - 2415021.076998695) / 29.530588853)
        var monthStart: Int = getNewMoonDay(k + 1, timeZone)

        if (monthStart > dayNumber) {
            monthStart = getNewMoonDay(k, timeZone)
        }

        var a11: Int = getLunarMonth11(yy, timeZone)
        var b11: Int = a11

        if (a11 >= monthStart) {
            lunarYear = yy
            a11 = getLunarMonth11(yy-1, timeZone)
        } else {
            lunarYear = yy + 1
            b11 = getLunarMonth11(yy + 1, timeZone)
        }

        lunarDay = dayNumber - monthStart + 1
        var diff: Int = INT((monthStart - a11)/29)
        lunarLeap = 0
        lunarMonth = diff + 11

        if (b11 - a11 > 365) {
            var leapMonthDiff: Int = getLeapMonthOffset(a11, timeZone)
            if (diff >= leapMonthDiff) {
                lunarMonth = diff + 10
                if (diff == leapMonthDiff) {
                    lunarLeap = 1
                }
            }
        }
        if (lunarMonth > 12) {
            lunarMonth = lunarMonth - 12
        }
        if (lunarMonth >= 11 && diff < 4) {
            lunarYear = lunarYear - 1
        }
        return [lunarDay, lunarMonth, lunarYear, lunarLeap]
    }

    func convertLunar2Solar(_ lunarDay: Int, _ lunarMonth: Int, _ lunarYear: Int, _ lunarLeap: Int, _ timeZone: Double) -> [Int]{
        var a11: Int = 0
        var b11: Int = 0

        if (lunarMonth < 11) {
            a11 = getLunarMonth11(lunarYear-1, timeZone)
            b11 = getLunarMonth11(lunarYear, timeZone)
        } else {
            a11 = getLunarMonth11(lunarYear, timeZone)
            b11 = getLunarMonth11(lunarYear+1, timeZone)
        }

        var k: Int = INT(0.5 + (a11 - 2415021.076998695) / 29.530588853)
        var off: Int = lunarMonth - 11

        if (off < 0) {
            off = off + 12
        }

        if (b11 - a11 > 365) {
            var leapOff: Int = getLeapMonthOffset(a11, timeZone)
            var leapMonth: Int = leapOff - 2

            if (leapMonth < 0) {
                leapMonth = leapMonth + 12
            }

            if (lunarLeap != 0 && lunarMonth != leapMonth) {
                //debugPrint("Invalid input!")
                return new [0, 0, 0]
            } else if (lunarLeap != 0 || off >= leapOff) {
                off = off + 1
            }
        }

        let monthStart: Int = getNewMoonDay(k + off, timeZone)

        return jdToDate(monthStart+lunarDay-1)
    }
}
```

#### update 1:

```
//
//  DateExtensions.swift
//  Sonar2Lunar
//
//  Created by Nguyen Thanh Hai on 5/7/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Nguyen Thanh Hai. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import SwiftDate

class DateExtensions {
    let PI: Double = M_PI

    func jdFromDate(_ day: Int, _ month: Int, _ year: Int) ->Int {
        let a: Int = (14 - month) / 12
        let y: Int = year + 4800 - a
        let m: Int = month + 12 * a - 3
        var jd: Int = day + (153 * m + 2)/5 + 365 * y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 - 32045

        if (jd < 2299161) {
            jd = day + (153 * m + 2)/5 + 365 * y + y/4 - 32083
        }

        return jd
    }

    func jdToDate(_ jd: Int) -> [Int] {
        var a: Int = 0
        var b: Int = 0
        var c: Int = 0

        if (jd > 2299160) { // After 5/10/1582, Gregorian calendar
            a = jd + 32044
            b = (4 * a + 3) / 146097
            c = a - (b * 146097) / 4
        } else {
            b = 0
            c = jd + 32082
        }
        let d: Int = (4 * c + 3)/1461
        let e: Int = c - (1461 * d)/4
        let m: Int = (5 * e + 2)/153
        let day: Int = e - (153 * m + 2)/5 + 1
        let month: Int = m + 3 - 12 * (m/10)
        let year: Int = b * 100 + d - 4800 + m/10

        return [day, month, year]
    }

    func INT(_ d: Double) -> Int {
        return Int(exactly: floor(d))!
    }

    func SunLongitude(_ jdn: Double) -> Double {
        return SunLongitudeAA98(jdn)
    }

    func SunLongitudeAA98(_ jdn: Double) -> Double {
        let T: Double = (jdn - 2451545.0 ) / 36525 // Time in Julian centuries from 2000-01-01 12:00:00 GMT
        let T2: Double = T * T
        let dr: Double = PI/180 // degree to radian
        let M: Double = 357.52910 + 35999.05030 * T - 0.0001559 * T2 - 0.00000048 * T * T2 // mean anomaly, degree
        let L0: Double = 280.46645 + 36000.76983 * T + 0.0003032 * T2 // mean longitude, degree
        var DL: Double = (1.914600 - 0.004817 * T - 0.000014 * T2) * sin(dr * M)
        DL = DL + (0.019993 - 0.000101 * T) * sin(dr * 2 * M) + 0.000290 * sin(dr * 3 * M)
        var L: Double = L0 + DL // true longitude, degree
        L = L - Double(360 * (INT(L/360))) // Normalize to (0, 360)

        return L
    }
}
```

Comment: The expression `Int(exactly: floor(d))` doesn't compile at all on my machine.

Comment: The expression `Double(L - 360 * (INT(L/360)))` doesn't compile on my machine.

Comment: The expression `dayNumber - 0.5 - timeZone/24` doesn't compile on my machine.

Comment: so which expression could I replace ? tks

Comment: The problem is that your code is so riddled with compile errors that the compiler can't deal with it. It almost seems like you just pasted all this code in from some other language and are expecting Swift to deal with it. It can't. Your code is junk as far as Swift is concerned.

Comment: @matt, 
please take a look into code update #2, I just removed any func then compiler is now faster than original code.
that code Double(360 * (INT(L/360))) are complied succeed.

You right, I am trying to port the algorithm from java to Swift. 
https://www.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/~duc/amlich/VietCalendar.java
Do you mean we cannot convert others algorithm to Swift ?

Comment: Even this line doesn't compile: `var T: Double = k/1236.85`. It is clear you know nothing at all about Swift numerics. You need to build your code up _one line at a time_, compiling after each line and fixing it. You cannot throw a file with 100 bad lines at Swift; it can't take it.

Comment: Thanks @matt, I will re-implement line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is partly that you know nothing of Swift numerics, and partly that Swift is not very good at handling large amounts of bad numeric code. A particularly egregious spot is:

```
func NewMoonAA98(_ k: Int) -> Double {
    var T: Double = k/1236.85 // Time in Julian centuries from 1900 January 0.5
    var T2: Double = T * T
    var T3: Double = T2 * T
    var dr: Double = PI/180
    var Jd1: Double = Double(2415020.75933 + 29.53058868*k + 0.0001178*T2 - 0.000000155*T3)
```

Those lines *alone* are enough to send both the parser and the compiler in to a complete tailspin. *You cannot combine an Int and a Double in the same expression*. So this line:

```
    var T: Double = k/1236.85 // Time in Julian centuries from 1900 January 0.5
```

needs to be

```
    var T: Double = Double(k)/1236.85 // Time in Julian centuries from 1900 January 0.5
```

and this line:

```
    var Jd1: Double = Double(2415020.75933 + 29.53058868*k + 0.0001178*T2 - 0.000000155*T3)
```

needs to be

```
    var Jd1: Double = Double(2415020.75933 + 29.53058868*Double(k) + 0.0001178*T2 - 0.000000155*T3)
```

Those kinds of mistakes permeate your code, and the result is that the compiler is basically spinning its wheels; your code is such a numeric mess that the compiler doesn't know where to start to pinpoint the errors, they are so numerous and so mutually dependent. You could submit your code to Apple as a bug report, but really you could make more of an effort to be kind to the compiler.

Comment: I have finished Swift code and published to the github at https://github.com/haithngn/SoluDate

Thank you for your very very helpful advices!

Comment: Excellent! — I still think you should submit your original code to Apple at `bugs.swift.org`. Even though your code had many compilation errors, you have a right to expect the compiler at least to find one and stop, rather than just hanging forever.

Comment: I will do that :).